Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(9\sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7})$
Consider the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq F$ where $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$.
Let $H = \mathbb{Q}(9\sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7})$. Determine $\mathrm{Gal}(F/H)$.
I supposed that since $\alpha=9\sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7} \in F$, and $H\subseteq F$, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $H$ is $x-\alpha$, so $[F:H]=\deg(x-\alpha)=1$, so $\mathrm{Gal}(F/H)=\{e\}$.
Is my reasoning mathematically correct to show that $F=H$ and find $\mathrm{Gal}(F/H)$?

Surely $\deg(x-\alpha)=1$ implies that $[H:H]=1$. What that has to do with $[F:H]$, I don't understand.

Hint: look at a proof of the primitive element theorem.

A different hint: show that the only automorphism of $\text{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$ that fixes $\alpha$ is the identity.

It is very known that $H=F$

Fixed the MathJax and the title (which was way too generic before).

We indeed have $H=F$, but your proof is not correct. You have only shown $[H:H]=1$, which is trivial (see also the comments). To prove $H=F$, we use the following
Constructive primitive element theorem. Let $F$ be a field, $a_1,b_1$ algebraic over $F$ with conjugates $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$, $b_1,\dotsc,b_m$. Assume that $b$ is separable over $F$. Assume that $\lambda \in F$ is an element such that
$$\lambda \neq - \frac{a_1 - a_i}{b_1 - b_j}$$
for all $i,j > 1$. Then $F(a_1,b_1) = F(a_1 + \lambda b_1)$.
This is actually proven in most treatments of the primitive element theorem, also on Wikipedia.
Here, we let $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $a_1 = 9 \sqrt{5}$, $b_1 = \sqrt{7}$, and $\lambda = 2$.  For this to work, we only need to verify that
$$2 \neq - \frac{9 \sqrt{5} - (-9 \sqrt{5})}{\sqrt{7} - (-\sqrt{7})}.$$
That's easy. It follows from the constructive primitive element theorem that
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(9 \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(9 \sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7}).$$

Alternatively, if you already know the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$: It has order $4$ and consists of the automorphisms mapping $\sqrt{5} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{7} \mapsto \pm \sqrt{7}$. Now, observe that the three automorphisms corresponding to the sign combinations $(+,-)$, $(-,+)$, and $(-,-)$ do not fix $9 \sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7}$. For example, in the first one we map this element to $9 \sqrt{5} - 2 \sqrt{7}$, which is not equal to $9 \sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7}$. Hence, the identity is the only element in the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(9 \sqrt{5} + 2 \sqrt{7})$.
A similar argument shows $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(u \sqrt{5} + v \sqrt{7})$ for all $u,v \in \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$.

What do you think of my comment to OP above?

Well you would need to prove that $[H:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, which is not immediate when you think about the details. You can explain it in your own answer.

You're correct; I found that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4 - 866 x^2 + 142129$, but I didn't find an easy way to show that polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q,$ but I did find an alternative answer (q.v.)

I'll note that you don't even need to know the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. With $2$ generators it's easy, but this argument can be extended to $n$ square roots, and then you don't need to know there are precisely $2^n$ automorphisms. (which is not even always true, and even when it is, that's non trivial) All what matters is that if $\sigma$ is not the identity automorphism then it can't fix both $\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{7}$, and at least one of them must be mapped to its additive inverse, which results a strictly smaller number than $\alpha$.

As Martin Brandenburg answered, you are correct that $F=H$, but your proof is inadequate.
You noted that $H\subseteq F$, so it remains to show that $F\subseteq H$.
Note that $\alpha^3=(9\sqrt5+2\sqrt7)^3=4401\sqrt5+2486\sqrt7$ by binomial expansion.
Now can you show, by taking linear combinations of $\alpha^3 $ and $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$,
that $\sqrt5,\sqrt7\in H$, so $F\subseteq H$?
